# How do I find out what function call_user_func is calling

Tags: php, nextcloud

I am very much a beginner at PHP.

I am trying to debug a serious problem with our Nextcloud installation.
It is taking ages (4-10 secs) to open a file using fopen (as defined in `lib/private/Files/View.php`).

The bit which takes the time is in the function runHooks. This is calling emit (in `lib/private/legacy/OC_HOOK.php`). This has the following code:

```
        foreach (self::$registered[$signalClass][$signalName] as $i) {
            try {
                call_user_func([ $i["class"], $i["name"] ], $params);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                self::$thrownExceptions[] = $e;
                \OC::$server->getLogger()->logException($e);
                if ($e instanceof \OC\HintException) {
                    throw $e;
                }
                if ($e instanceof \OC\ServerNotAvailableException) {
                    throw $e;
                }
            }
        }
```

The class is empty, and the name is "read".

How do I find the source code for the function being called?

Comment: Sounds like you need to search for `function read(` within your codebase

Comment: Yes, there are about 20 such functions. How do I find out which one?

Comment: If none is in the same script/class file, start looking for one in the same namespace, the `use` statements. Maybe some `include` or `require` statements. Easiest way, use the debugger. Worst way, stuff a `var_dump` into every single one.

Comment: _"The class is empty"_ - then this should throw a warning (PHP 7) resp. a fatal error (PHP 8) to begin with.